# Data saved not as Data requested

Tags: java, android, file-io, android-listview

I want to store a specific data on a file, the operation is done BUT not as requested!
Code:

```
if (value1 != null && value1.trim().length() > 0 && value2 != null && value2.trim().length() > 0)
{
    float q1=Float.parseFloat(vol.getText().toString());
    float q2=Float.parseFloat(kil.getText().toString());
    float x=((q1 / q2)* 100);
    String y= Float.toString(x);
    cons.setText(y);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
    String date = format.format(new Date());
    data = date + " : " + y + " L/100km\n" + value1 + " L "+ value2 + " KM\n";
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (data != "" ) 
    {
        String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
        String fileDir = ""+ preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
        myIO.WriteSettings(context, fileDir + fileName, data);
        data = ""; 
    }
```

In my ListView I have (example): `17/03 : 8.5L/100km`
But I'd like to have this (as I did in the code!): `17/03 : 8.5L/100km 20L 300KM`.

WriteSettings():

```
public class myIO {
public static void WriteSettings(Context context, String nom, String data) {
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

    try {
        fOut = context.openFileOutput(nom, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        try {
            osw.close();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: did you mean to have the newline after `100km\n` ?

Comment: @willytate: I tried to have a newline(\n) and not, the both don't work :\

Comment: if you print `data` with a `Log.d()` after assigning it what do you get?

Comment: Sorry, but i never used log.d()! can you please tell me what to do ? Thanks :).

Comment: `Log.d("MyApp", data);` this will print the value to `logcat`

Comment: @willytate: i have this : 03-17 12:56:51.194: DEBUG/Carburant(627): 17/03 : 10.0 L/100km20 L 200 KM
(WITHOUT \n)

Comment: What is the `WriteSettings()` function? Is this something you made?

Comment: (WITH \n): 03-17 13:03:36.425: DEBUG/Carburant(660): 17/03 : 10.0 L/100km/n20 L 200 KM

Comment: Yes, it's a method in an other class ! The strange thing that the data is well saved but not well displayed :\ !

Comment: so the data DOES makes it to the file the way you want it?

Comment: Yes, i think it saves correctly: the log.d() displays this(with \n) : 03-17 13:10:48.604: DEBUG/Carburant(694): 17/03 : 10.0 L/100km
03-17 13:10:48.604: DEBUG/Carburant(694): 20 L 200 KM. And without a \n i have this: 03-17 12:56:51.194: DEBUG/Carburant(627): 17/03 : 10.0 L/100km20 L 200 KM 
So the data is saved correctly, no ?

Comment: Something could be going wrong in your "WriteSettings()" function you may want to post the code for that as well and maybe someone can find a problem in it.

Comment: Also, how are you extracting that value later and displaying it in your `ListView`?  It seems the value should be getting saved properly.

Comment: The activity(class) that shows the datas has this function, see comment...

Comment: @willytate: i don't know how but it works now! sometimes it said that there is no data saved and sometimes it shows me the datas as requested ! i don't know why there is sometimes a problem, i'll re-look on the whole code. Thank you anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void updatelv(Activity activity) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
    fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
    s = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(getApplicationContext(), fileDir+fileName);
    ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    L.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, s[0]));
}
```

When displaying make this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.histo);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    activity = this;
    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
    fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."
            + preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
    s = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(getApplicationContext(), fileDir + fileName);

    **updatelv(this);**
```

So? :\